# Castle Windsor Project Includes in Config

Tags: web-config, castle-windsor

I want the properties section of the Castle config to be included from another file. I.e:

```
<castle>
  <include uri="file://properties.config" />
</castle>
```

The properties.config would then look like:

```
<properties>
  <smtp>10.10.10.10</smtp>
  <username>john</username>
</properties>
```

I can get the include to work for components but not for properties. If I try to do this with properties I get an exception thrown. Is this a limitation of Castle?

Comment: What exception do you have? How do you read the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a misunderstanding about how I should be entering the xml into the configuration. I wasn't starting with the castle element and working down, i.e. I was using properties as the root node.